# Very slight discontinuities in table borders

Tags: tables, rules

Tables in LaTeX all seem to have slight discontinuities in the outside vertical borders - little notches that are only really visible if you zoom in.  Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & B \\ 
    \hline
    C & D \\ 
    \hline
    E & F \\
    \hline
    G & H \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example pic of table]

I'm surprised I couldn't find mention of this when I Googled, given how common tables are.  Is there some obscure typographical rule that tables should have little notches like this?  Is there any good way to get rid of them?  Because they kind of bug me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fixed with the use of the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    A & B \\ 
    \hline
    C & D \\ 
    \hline
    E & F \\
    \hline
    G & H \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is mentioned in the [`array` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I should have guessed there would be a package to do that.  As far as I can tell, there's a package to do just about anything.

Comment: … except maybe answer any TeX-related question. Except if you consider tex.stackexchange to be a package, of course ;)

Answer (score 8):

Please pardon me for channeling my inner [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) evangelist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\ 
    \midrule
    C & D \\ 
    E & F \\
    G & H \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You might not think much of the difference with this small table, but when looking at a larger and/or more complex table it is much easier for your eyes to examine the data/contents without being distracted by lines everywhere.

You might find some other pointers in an excellent animated GIF created by [Darkhorse Analytics](http://darkhorseanalytics.com/): [How to make your tables less terrible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv3aJ.gif) (Reddit's title, not my judgment of your table... :~) )

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  As it happens, I only need a 2x5 table in this particular case.  However, I'll certainly keep your advice in mind if I need more complex tables in the future.  Also, that is a pretty sweet GIF.