# Cell color with horizontal rule in tabular environment

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to draw the following figure in latex:

[image]

However, some of my horizontal lines appear to be blurred by the cellcolor and some vertical lines don't show up at all. Anyone knows a way to get round this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|llll|}
    \hhline{*{4}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hhline{*{4}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}}

    \cellcolor{blue} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hhline{*{4}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}}

    \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 3 & 4 \\\hhline{*{4}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}}

    \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 4 \\\hhline{*{4}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) to insert the rules. Instead, use [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) which does [a better job at connecting corners in a `tabular`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223195/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{l|} }
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \cellcolor{blue} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 4 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've ran the code and noticed the horizontal line immediately under 1 and the one after doesn't show. I do see a *thin* horizontal line though when I zoom in to about 400%!

Comment: @iab : This is dependant on your reader/viewer and not related to LaTeX. I use SumatraPDF.

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat Reader. Since I can't make any assumptions about what reader/viewer users of the document will use (I'm only knowing of Sumatra now), it appears I'll have to find some other way of highlighting the cells. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @iab: You can make all the rules thicker by adjusting `\arrayrulewidth`. The default is `.4pt` (say `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}`), which is lost as many zoom levels under Adobe (Acrobat) Reader. Different viewers have different rendering techniques, which you can't control for (but it is worth noting).

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to face that kind of problem. It provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of `array`) but the rules and colored panels are drawn by PGF/Tikz. The output will be perfect in all PDF viewers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \cellcolor{blue} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 3 & 4 \\
  \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & \cellcolor{blue} & 4 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

One more solution, for completeness ...

With `tabularray` the following result ca be achieved:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             cells = {c},
             cell{2}{1}   = {bg=blue6},
             cell{3}{1-2} = {bg=blue6},
             cell{4}{1-3} = {bg=blue6}
             }
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    &   & 3 & 4 \\
    &   &   & 4 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
The same result can be achieved by defining new command for coloring cells, for example `\NewTableCommand\bc{\SetCell{bg=blue6}}` and than use it in each table cell which should be colored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTableCommand\bc{\SetCell{bg=blue6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             cells = {c},
             }
  1 &   2 &  3 & 4 \\
\bc &   2 &  3 & 4 \\
\bc &\bc  &  3 & 4 \\
\bc &\bc  &\bc & 4 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Result of compilation is the same as before.